# How do I retain query params in the pagination URLs in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-paginator

I am using Zend\Paginator to construct a paginated result set. This works fine, however, after adding a search form, I cannot get the two to play nicely together.

The URL produced by the search form on the page is:

```
user/index/?searchTerm=hello
```

How do I amend the Zend paginator configuration so that it retains the searchTerm in the URLs produced?

I was hoping for something like:

```
user/index/page/4/?searchTerm=hello
```

What am I missing?

---

The module config route is defined as follows:

```
'user' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/user[/[:action[/]]][[id/:id]][/[page/:page]]',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\User',
            'action'     => 'index',
            'id'         => null,
        ),

        // the below was added to try and get the searchTerm query to be retained
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes'  => array(
            'searchTerm' => array(
                'type' => 'Query',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

The pagination is constructed using this in the view:

```
echo $this->paginationControl(
        $this->users, 'sliding', array('paginator', 'User'), array('route' => 'user', 'action' => 'index')
    );
```

Pagination template snippet:

```
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('action' => $this->action, 'page' => $this->next), true); ?>">
            Next &raquo;
        </a>
    </li>
```

(I was under the impression that passing `true` as the [third parameter to `url()` would retain the query params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637051/zf2-using-url-helper-and-reuse-query-parameters).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now see what that third parameter to `url()` is doing. I can simplify the pagination links and remove the 'action' key as follows:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $this->next), true); ?>">
```

The page's action was matched as part of the URL (due to that third param being true) which is why that works. By the same token I can change the route to this:

```
'route' => '/user[/[:action[/]]][[id/:id]][/[page/:page]][/[search/:search]]',
```

And then the `search` will be retained in the pagination links.

If I amend the search form to submit via JavaScript, I can construct the search URL and direct the user to it.

Simple jQuery example for that approach:

```
$(".search-form").submit(function() {
    var baseUrl = $(this).attr('action'),
        search = $(this).find('.search').val();

     window.location = baseUrl + '/search/' + search;

    return false;
});
```

Another option would be to redirect to the `current/route/search/term` route in the controller if it receives a searchTerm query.

I'm posting this as an answer but I am open to better solutions.